# Do all AC-DC converters produce current spikes in input?

Tags: ltspice, rectifier, ac-dc

I am designing a simple rectifier circuit with LTSpice (I am planning to build one for myself) and I found out that AC-DC converters require PFC circuits to prevent huge input spikes (?). I tried doing a few examples (one with L6561) I found on the internet, but they still make spikes - smaller, but they exist (input power is up to 6.3kW, while output is barely ~400W). Shouldn't proper PFC prevent them and make input current smooth and continuous?

Or do they just make output voltage smooth?

Is there a way to make smoother converter?

Comment: Not really. Is it the initial capacitor charging inrush current you are referring to or steady state operation?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the ac-to-dc conversion is done by the diode bridge and the capacitor. The downstream converter is a high-voltage dc-dc converter. The input current waveform you see is linked to the capacitor refueling at the top of the input sine and these narrow spikes are rich in harmonics. If you absorb more than 75 W of power, outside of lighting, then yes, you need a front-end PFC stage.

Comment: If you insert an inductor immediately after the bridge, one can lower the peak charging current of the capacitor ... simple, but at the cost of a "heavy" inductor ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am designing a simple rectifier circuit with LTSpice (I am planning to build one for myself) and I found out that AC-DC converters require PFC circuits to prevent huge input spikes (?).

As Verbal Kint hints to, designs over 75W should have some level of remediation applied to these "input spikes."  But what do you mean by "input spikes?"

> I tried doing a few examples (one with L6561) I found on the internet, but they still make spikes - smaller, but they exist (input power is up to 6.3kW, while output is barely ~400W).

An *ideal* capacitor, when connected to a voltage source, has zero internal series resistance, so will draw *infinite* current for some infinitely small amount of time.  Be careful of simulators and equations which ignore the capacitors (and PCB's) series resistance, as they can often be important, especially for inrush.

But I think we're talking about different things here:

- A *linear* DC supply *rectifies* 50/60Hz AC using a *bridge rectifier* and charges a *smoothing capacitor*.  The bigger the smoothing capacitor, the less DC ripple (but the more inrush current required to charge it.) Since the input power drawn is mostly used to "top-off" the filter capacitor, the current is non-sinusoidal, so creates a reduced line AC power-factor.
- A *switching* DC supply, first rectifies 50/60Hz AC using a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor (note, same thing so far), then pulses this high DC voltage to a high-frequency transformer or inductor, at a much higher frequency. The pulse width determines the output voltage, so often the IC is some form of PWM controller.  Note that a switching supply itself, from the line AC side, doesn't appear much different than a linear supply (non-sinusoidal current is drawn, leading to a reduced power factor.) The high-frequency switching noise can also be radiated into the line power, so even more filtering components are required.
- The [L6561](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6561.pdf) is a *power-factor correction* controller.  This has some similarities to a switching controller, but is specifically optimized to *improve power factor* by emulating sinusoidal current draw from the mains. These *also* employ smoothing/filtering capacitors, and *will* cause an inrush current. The PFC emulates sinusoidal current draw by pulsing an inductor very quickly; the width of these pulses resulting in an average sinusoidal current from the mains.

6.3kW "inrush current" is a lot, but *for how long?*  If this only lasts one or two AC cycles, is it really an issue?  All AC/DC supplies have an inrush current requirement, because filtering capacitors are needed.

A modern PC power supply, will draw likely 50A from the mains for a cycle or two when first connected. This is normal and accepted behavior.

> Shouldn't proper PFC prevent them and make input current smooth and continuous?

No not really.  PFC is there to *draw sinusoidal current from the mains*, not *be a soft-start.*

> Is there a way to make smoother converter?

Typically, capacitor "pre-charge" circuitry could be employed.  However, this means a longer start-up time.  "Precharge" means to add some temporary resistance in series to those large capacitors, to limit the inrush current peak value.  Careful attention to the duration and power across that resistor may dictate it to be 5, 10, 20W or more in size and be "pulse-rated." Sometimes NTC/PTC thermistor(s) may be used instead to help elongate this charging time.  Then, after some amount of charging time, a relay or MOSFET is closed across that precharge resistor for normal full-power operation.  The net result is a reduced inrush current, but slower start-up.

For a 400W design this may mean orchestrating things (PFC precharge, DC-DC precharge) with the help of significant additional circuitry, such as a microcontroller.

Comment: Note that for very large designs, a phase-angle SCR soft-start may be used.  These control the firing angle of SCR's (instead of resistors) to limit the amount of power delivered to the large capacitors.  These waste less power as heat, but are more complex.

Answer (score 1):

If one will take a look at this "passive" filter.

Only "steady-state" ... Pictures for voltages, currents, powers, and efficiency (UEO).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this works, but inductors are very large (too large I think - as you mentioned "heavy") - are there 1 farad inductors with suitable low resistance on market? mouser.com has nothing like it

Comment: I used "heavy" because PFC can be "light" ... Transformers for 50/60 Hz have also "high" inductance because of the "iron" used and little air gap, and I think this is not "impracticable" ... The capacitors are 1 mF, "coupled inductors" are 1 Henry :-) , in fact it could be a "transformer" (with right power).

Comment: @RiDi  I have also simulated the last circuit with L1=L2=100mH, and C1=100 uF with "same" diagrams.